# How can you enter zoom conferencing details in the `conferenceData` parameter?

Tags: google-calendar-api

**Google Calendar Docs** suggest that there is an way to enter 3P links. But, I failed after multiple attempts. Is there any way to do so?

I tried different ways to enter details into `conferenceData` object. Tried `insert`, `update` and `patch`.

Code Snippet

```
const insertEvent = await calendar.events.insert({
    calendarId: "primary",
    sendNotifications: true,
    supportsAttachments: true,
    requestBody: {
      summary: "Hell Yeah",
      start: {
        dateTime: "2022-03-25T08:30:00.000Z",
        timeZone: "Asia/Kolkata",
      },
      end: {
        dateTime: "2022-03-25T09:30:00.000Z",
        timeZone: "Asia/Kolkata",
      },
      conferenceData: {
        conferenceId: "93831668388",
        conferenceSolution: {
          iconUri: "https://st1.zoom.us/static/6.0.5527/image/new/ZoomLogo.png",
          key: { type: "addOn" },
          name: "Zoom",
        },
        entryPoints: [
          {
            entryPointType: "video",
            label: "zoom.us/j/93831668388?pwd=UHRqU0VwMjF3d1B0VXU5bFBRYWIxdz09",
            passcode: "4gnZXJ",
            uri: "https://zoom.us/j/93831668388?pwd=UHRqU0VwMjF3d1B0VXU5bFBRYWIxdz09",
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  });
```

But the event was created without any zoom meeting links.

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example] and describe any issues you are having include an error message.    You can only add confrence data type of the type that the calendar is set to. If the calendar isnt set to zoom (not sure it can be) then its not going to let you insert that type.

Comment: I have updated the post with a code snippet @DaImTo.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your request is the `iconUri`. Your request will work without it. The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events) does not specify any requirement for `iconUri`, however, I tried with multiple formats (png, SVG, jpg, etc.) and it's not clear to me what the restrictions are, even the [icon](https://ssl.gstatic.com/calendar/images/conferenceproviders/logo_meet_2020q4_192px.svg) they use for Google Meet will fail. One example of a working `iconUri` is the [one](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/pw/AM-JKLUkiyTEgH-6DiQP85RGtd_BORvAuFnS9katNMgwYQBJUTiDh12qtQxMJFWYH2Dj30hNsNUrr-kzKMl7jX-Qd0FR7JmVSx-Fhruf8xTPPI-wdsMYez6WJE7tz7KmqsORKBEnBTiILtMJXuMvphqKdB9X=s128-no) used by the Zoom add-on.

The minimal working example is something like this:

```
conferenceData: {
    conferenceSolution: {
      key: { type: "addOn" },
      name: "Zoom",
    },
    entryPoints: [
      {
        entryPointType: "video",
        passcode: "4gnZXJ",
        uri: "https://zoom.us/j/93831668388?pwd=UHRqU0VwMjF3d1B0VXU5bFBRYWIxdz09",
      },
    ],
  },
```

Something similar to the one generated by the plugin will be like this:

```
"conferenceData": {
"entryPoints": [
  {
    "entryPointType": "video",
    "uri": "https://zoom.us/j/93831668388?pwd=UHRqU0VwMjF3d1B0VXU5bFBRYWIxdz09",
    "label": "zoom.us/j/93831668388?pwd=UHRqU0VwMjF3d1B0VXU5bFBRYWIxdz09",
    "meetingCode": "93831668388",
    "passcode": "4gnZXJ"
  },
  {
    "regionCode": "US",
    "entryPointType": "phone",
    "uri": "tel:+13092053325,,89815701514#",
    "label": "+1 309-205-3325",
    "passcode": "2753507469"
  },
  {
    "regionCode": "IE",
    "entryPointType": "phone",
    "uri": "tel:+35316533895,,89815701514#",
    "label": "+353 1 653 3895",
    "passcode": "2753507469"
  },
  {
    "entryPointType": "more",
    "uri": "https://applications.zoom.us/addon/invitation/detail?meetingUuid%3D%252BEfhBWj1RaeatV6Qo4QPeg%253D%253D%26signature%1a2E5Aa06313c4d378f6a231d83a13eec96f1643f81e300de80bf9eb4784b91440%26v%3D1&sa=D&source=calendar&usg=AOvVaw2jZJmsX7bEbWL1wVde7dOM"
  }
],
"conferenceSolution": {
  "key": {
    "type": "addOn"
  },
  "name": "Zoom Meeting",
  "iconUri": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/pw/AM-JKLUkiyTEgH-6DiQP85RGtd_BORvAuFnS9katNMgwYQBJUTiDh12qtQxMJFWYH2Dj30hNsNUrr-kzKMl7jX-Qd0FR7JmVSx-Fhruf8xTPPI-wdsMYez6WJE7tz7KmqsORKBEnBTiILtMJXuMvphqKdB9X=s128-no"
},
"conferenceId": "93831668388",
"notes": "Meeting host: <a href=\"mailto:meeting_creator@mail.com\" target=\"_blank\" > meeting_creator@mail.com</a> <br> <br> Join Zoom Meeting: <br> <a href=\"meeting_creator@mail.com\" target=\"_blank\" > https://zoom.us/j/93831668388?pwd=UHRqU0VwMjF3d1B0VXU5bFBRYWIxdz09 </a>"  
}
```